# avoid pointer-to-member-function for non-class type

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am writing a kind of container class, for which I would like to offer an `apply` method which evaluates a function on the content of the container.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T val;

    /** apply a free function */
    template<typename U> Foo<U> apply(U(*fun)(const T&))
    {
        return Foo<U>(fun(val));
    }

    /** apply a member function */
    template<typename U> Foo<U> apply(U (T::*fun)() const)
    {
        return Foo<U>((val.*fun)());
    }
};

struct Bar{};
template class Foo<Bar>; // this compiles
//template class Foo<int>; // this produces an error
```

The last line yields `error: creating pointer to member function of non-class type ‘const int’`. **Even though I only instantiated `Foo` and not used `apply` at all**. So my question is: How can I effectively remove the second overload whenever `T` is a non-class type?

Note: I also tried having only one overload taking a `std::function<U(const T&)>`. This kinda works, because both function-pointers and member-function-pointers can be converted to `std::function`, but this approach effectively disables template deduction for `U` which makes user-code less readable.

Comment: [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) could be useful here.

Comment: I'd advise against using member function pointers if it could be helped at all, they are messy beyond imagination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `std::invoke` instead helps, it is much easier to implement and read

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T val;

    template<typename U> auto apply(U&& fun)
    {
        return Foo<std::invoke_result_t<U, T>>{std::invoke(std::forward<U>(fun), val)};
    }
};

struct Bar{};
template class Foo<Bar>;
template class Foo<int>;
```

However, this won't compile if the functions are overloaded

```
int f();
double f(const Bar&);
Foo<Bar>{}.apply(f);  // Doesn't compile
```

The way around that is to use functors instead

```
Foo<Bar>{}.apply([](auto&& bar) -> decltype(auto) { return f(decltype(bar)(bar)); });
```

Which also makes it more consistent with member function calls

```
Foo<Bar>{}.apply([](auto&& bar) -> decltype(auto) { return decltype(bar)(bar).f(); });
```

Comment: `return f(bar);` ---> `return f(std::forward<decltype(bar)>(bar))`

Comment: @liliscent I didn't want to bog the whole thing down with ten million tidbits of generic programming boilerplate. In fact, I didn't even want to write `decltype(auto)` at first. But in the name of completeness, here you go.

Comment: As a SO answer, I agree. However if you started writing `decltype(auto)` and `auto&&`, I think the completeness is needed. +1

Comment: This is indeed easier to read and possibly more flexible than my approach of adding multiple overloads. So I will use (and thus accept) this answer. But thanks a lot to the other answerers as well, this was quite educational.

Comment: c++17 would even allow `return Foo{std::invoke(std::forward<U>(fun), val)}`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to remove the second overload you'd need to make it a template and let SFINAE work, e. g. like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T val;

    //...

    /** apply a member function */
    template<typename U, typename ObjT>
    Foo<U> apply(U (ObjT::*fun)() const)
    {
        return Foo<U>((val.*fun)());
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could remove the second overload altogether, and use lambda or `std::bind:`

```
#include <functional> // for std::bind

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T val;

    /** apply a member function */
    template<typename U, typename FuncT>
    Foo<U> apply(FuncT&& f)
    {
        return {f(val)};
    }
};

struct SomeType
{
    int getFive() { return 5; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<SomeType> obj;

    obj.apply<int>(std::bind(&SomeType::getFive, std::placeholders::_1));
    obj.apply<int>([](SomeType& obj) { return obj.getFive(); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I effectively remove the second overload whenever T is a non-class type?

If you can use at least C++11 (and if you tried `std::function` I suppose you can use it), you can use SFINAE with `std::enable_if`

```
   template <typename U, typename V>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<V>{}
                        && std::is_same<V, T>{}, Foo<U>>::type
      apply(U (V::*fun)() const)
    { return Foo<U>((val.*fun)()); }
```

to impose that `T` is a class.

Observe that you can't check directly `T`, that is a template parameter of the class, but you have to pass through a `V` type, a template type of the specific method.

But you can also impose that `T` and `V` are the same type (`&& std::is_same<V, T>{}`).

Comment: You really don't need `enable_if` in here. If `V` is different from `T`, compiler will throw an error at `(val.*fun)()` without it. You don't need `std::is_class` either, having parameter of type `U (V::*)()` is enough to cause substitution failure for non-class types.

Comment: @joe_chip Downvote for this doesn't make sense. `enable_if` could serve as self-documenting. Moreover, those two have different semantics, you might want another overloading for a failed type instead of an hard-error. Though I agree with you on the `std::is_class` part.

Comment: IMHO, a comment (or changing `V` to e. g. `SameAsT`) would be better for documentation. Here, using `enable_if` just causes compiler to generate more confusing error. But yes, if you'd like to have another overload, then `enable_if` would be good choice.

Comment: @joe_chip - your point is correct but I've answered a precise question from the OP: "How can I effectively remove the second overload whenever T is a non-class type?"

Comment: @max66 alright, un-downvoted, although I really think that `enable_if` is an abuse here.

Comment: @joe_chip - where a worst error in my answer that deserved a downvote: in first version I've added a default value for a template type that is deduced.

Comment: I actually tried using enable_if myself, but used T directly which doesnt work (as you noted). So this is indeed the most precise answer to my question. I will probably use the version with `std::invoke` in the end, because its cleaner. But thanks a lot for the enlightenment on enable_if.

Comment: @Simon - yes: it's a common error. And yes: the `std::invoke()` one is a good solution.